# Kubernetes proxy connection

Tags: proxy, kubernetes

I am trying to play around with kubernetes and specifically the REST API. The steps to connect with the cluster API are listed [here](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/user-guide/accessing-the-cluster.html). However Im stuck in the first step i.e. running kubectl proxy

I try running this:

`kubectl --context='vagrant' proxy --port=8080 &`

which returns `error: couldn't read version from server: Get https://172.17.4.99:443/api: dial tcp 172.17.4.99:443: i/o timeout`

What does this mean? How do overcome it connect to the API?

Comment: It sounds like your vagrant install didn't work properly. Which directions are you following and what Kubernetes version are you trying to run?

Answer (score 0):

Check that your docker, proxy, kube-apiserver, kube-control-manager services are running without error. Check their status using `systemclt status your-service-name`. If the service is loaded but not running then restart the service by using `systemctl restart your-service-name`.